# How to run multiple instances of TICKR

Tags: command-line, multiple-instances

See the bottom of  [TICKR Help](http://www.newsrssticker.com/help.php#faq).

I have problems running multiple instances of the program "TICKR". However, I found a 'solution' on their website (link top), but it is too advanced for me.

The problem is that I don't know what to with this provided line:

```
/usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=1 -win_y=200 & /usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=2 -win_y=250
```

And if I were to figure out how to use it, I would still not know how to run the multiple instances.

Can anyone provide a little easier walkthrough?

Comment: You learn something new everyday, huh...

Comment: I was probably scared by the word 'script'.. Thanks slhck

Comment: But the instances will close when I close the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enter these lines in a Terminal, which you can open by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

You can also paste them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

What the command does is calling the TICKR executable two times. The ampersand `&` will allow you to do so – all in one line.

If you want those instances to survive after the terminal window has been closed, prefix them with `nohup`:

```
nohup /usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=1 -win_y=200 & nohup /usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=2 -win_y=250
```

Answer (score 2):

first open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and paste command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. OR you can type in terminal.

```
/usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=1 -win_y=200 & /usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=2 -win_y=250
```

this is actually two commands `/usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=1 -win_y=200` and `/usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=2 -win_y=250`

lets interpret this `/usr/bin/tickr` is path+executable file to make it more clear `/usr/bin/` is path (means reference where is the file) and `tickr` is executable file.`/usr/bin/tickr` runs `tickr` executable file.

if use `/usr/bin/tickr` to execute it always uses default parameters. Parameters are used to run executable with changed default parameters. So parameters are used to change behaviour.

there is many parameter on site you provided with different uses of it.

here first parameter is `-instance-id=1` Used when launching several instances simultaneously, each instance using its own config and dump files (to be effective, instance-id must be the 1st argument). Which states `id` is 1.

now second parameter `-win_y=200` which is used to give Window position - y

instances will be closed if you close terminal to prevent this prefix `nohup` to command. so it will become

`nohup /usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=1 -win_y=200 & /usr/bin/tickr -instance-id=2 -win_y=250`

you can use any number of parameters.

*hope this helps.*